# "UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character" When Writing to csv Using a Webscraper

Tags: python, csv, web-scraping, unicode, character-encoding

I've written a webscraper that scrapes NBA box score data off of [basketball-reference](https://www.basketball-reference.com). The specific webpage that my error:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u0107' in position 11: character maps to <undefined>`

is occurring on is [here](https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202003110MIA.html). Lastly, the specific player data that is tripping it up and throwing this specific UnicodeEncodeError is [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hxqKl.png) (although I am sure the error is more generalized and will be produced with any character that contains an obscure accent mark).

The minimal reproducible code:

```
def get_boxscore_basic_table(tag): #used to only get specific tables
    tag_id = tag.get("id")
    tag_class = tag.get("class")
    return (tag_id and tag_class) and ("basic" in tag_id and "section_wrapper" in tag_class and not "toggleable" in tag_class)

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml
import csv
import re

website = 'https://www.basketball-reference.com/boxscores/202003110MIA.html'

r = requests.get(website).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'lxml')

tables = soup.find_all(get_boxscore_basic_table)

in_file = open('boxscore.csv', 'w', newline='')
csv_writer = csv.writer(in_file)
column_names = ['Player','Name','MP','FG','FGA','FG%','3P','3PA','3P%','FT','FTA','FT%','ORB','DRB','TRB','AST','STL','BLK','TOV','PF','PTS','+/-']
csv_writer.writerow(column_names)

for table in tables:    
    rows = table.select('tbody tr')

    for row in rows:
        building_player = [] #temporary container to hold player and stats
        player_name = row.th.text 
        if 'Reserves' not in player_name: 
            building_player.append(player_name)

        stats = row.select('td.right')

        for stat in stats:
            building_player.append(stat.text)

        csv_writer.writerow(building_player) #writing to csv

in_file.close()
```

What is the best way around this?

I've seen some stuff online about changing the encoding and specifically using the`.encode('utf-8')` method on the string before writing to the csv but it seems that this .encode() method, although it stops an error from being thrown, has several of its own problems. For instance; `player_name.encode('utf-8')` before writing to csv turns the name 'Willy Hernangómez' into 'b'Willy Hernang\xc3\xb3mez'' within by csv... not exactly a step in the right direction.

Any help with this and an explanation as to what is happening would be much appreciated!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe you should use `open(...,  encoding='utf-8')` to write it with `utf-8`

Comment: first you have to show full error message - it shows which line of code makes problem. Maybe your problem is in different place.

Comment: `econde()` creates `bytes` data and then you could use `open(..., 'wb')` to write it in `bytes` mode.

Comment: @furas I am really supposed to put the entire traceback in the question title? The full traceback is like 30 lines long...

Comment: not in title - in question body. Title is only for title, not for description. Many times full error is more useful then your explanation what you get in error message. Maybe you should first check other questions to see what people put in question.

Answer (score 3):

use

```
in_file = open('boxscore.csv', 'w', newline='',  encoding='utf-8')
```

instead of

```
in_file = open('boxscore.csv', 'w', newline='')
```

and keep everything the same. Make sure you open Excel in [utf-8 encoding](https://www.itg.ias.edu/content/how-import-csv-file-uses-utf-8-character-encoding-0)